# ComboBox.Items.AddRange -- create a set of items that can be added to multiple ComboBoxes

Tags: c#, combobox

I'm having a hard time explaining how I'm going to use this, so let me just throw up a generic example.

Let's say I have three different combo boxes, Combo1, Combo2, and Combo3. I set up Combo1 like so:

```
Combo1.Items.AddRange(new object[] { "Apples", "Oranges", "Pears" };
```

Now, if that range of items is only ever going to be used in Combo1, this method is fine. However, I also want to be able to use that same range of items in Combo2 and Combo3. But, I don't want to type that same list of items for every single instance where the combo boxes might need them.

Can someone show me how to set up that group of objects, so I can pull it into multiple comboboxes? I know there's a way to do it, but the MSDN site can be really dense at times, and I'm having trouble getting everything set up correctly.

Comment: Try putting your items into a variable instead, then you can just do `comboBox2.Items.AddRange(items);`

Comment: What kind of variable would I use for that? Just a string, with commas separating each item? No, that can't be right, it would just see it as one big long item...

Comment: You already have it in your code.  Try `string[] items = new string[] { "Apples", "Oranges", "Pears" };`

Comment: Alright, yeah, I have that part already. However, when I try to grab that string with my ComboBox, I can't. What's the syntax for that? I was trying
    Combo1.Items.AddRange(items);
But it's giving me errors with that. A bunch of other stuff I tried to, to no avail. :(

Comment: `var items = string[] { "Apples", "Oranges", "Pears" };`, and then `comboBox1.Items.AddRange(items); comboBox2.Items.AddRange(items);`. It's that simple...

Comment: Oh boy. Lars, you were right. I just had my variable in the wrong spot. I feel silly now, thank you!

@WillMarcouiller: What will Var do differently for this, rather than using it as a string? (I'm not familiar with what 'var' is, just sounds like a really generic variable value.)

Comment: `var` is only a placeholder for the type that will be resolved on the right-hand side of the `=` operator, instead of deliberately write the type completely.